# Unable to create project in Google Cloud: "Cloud Service disabled by admin. Please contact admin to restore service"

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I try to create my first Google Project, and i got this error

> Create Project: My Project
>
> APPHOSTING_ADMIN Cloud Service disabled by admin. Please contact admin to restore service. com.google.apps.framework.request.StatusException:  generic::FAILED_PRECONDITION: APPHOSTING_ADMIN Cloud Service disabled by admin. Please contact admin to restore service

Anyone any idea?

I am the admin from the GSuite account. I had checked my permission stuff in my account and I don't think there is a place for me to disable me from using GCP.

Answer (score 25):

One possible reason for such error message would be the disabled G-Suite access to the `Google Developers Console` service.

Check in your [GSuite Admin console](https://admin.google.com) `Apps` -> `Additional Google services` if `Google Developers Console` is enabled:

[image]

If it's not - enable it and re-try

Comment: This feature is no longer available in the G Suite console.

Comment: I have an older domain, and Cloud console is enabled for my domain, but I do not see 'Gogole Devlopers console' at all in the list of additional Google Services all in my GSuite admin console...
Even weirder, it shows up as a suggested search result, but not actually go to it!

Comment: @RedPandaCurios Yep, I see the same, something changed. Follow the related post I referenced in the update, an up2date solution may be found for it.

Comment: This seems to have been fixed now - I can now see Developers console in GSuite Admin -> Apps -> Addtional Google Services, So you should now be able to enable this app. 
https://admin.google.com/ac/appslist/additional

Answer (score 11):

Sorry to bump an old thread - but I just ran into this and wasted 20 minutes trying to figure out. Google Cloud Project (and Dev Console) were on for everyone but I could not create a project logged in as the Super Admin.

Go to Apps and click on Google Cloud Console. There's a single option 'Allow users to create projects' and for some reason in this company's tenant... It was unchecked. Checked it and project created. Bizarre. Has always been on for other clients apparently.

Comment: Just encountered this too. Thanks for your answer. I'm guessing Google changed their backend options, since none of those options from others exist anymore.

Comment: Thanks for this bump. This should be accepted as the real answer

Answer (score 4):

It seems I had the same or a similar issue- "google cloud platform service has been disabled error". Due to it, I could not create projects.

It seems the trouble was related to my university's email account
foo@mail.huji.ac.il. Once I used my gmail account the problem was solved.

Answer (score 4):

This response from Google support resolved the issue for us:

```
To activate this service, please follow the steps: 
1- Access the admin console and go to Apps -> Additional Google Services 
2- Look for the service “Google Cloud Platform” and click on the box next to it 
3- In to top right corner click in “ON” 
4- Confirm you want to turn it on in the pop-up box.
```