# Google Maps Platform unable to create project (Google Cloud Platform service has been disabled)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-cloud-platform, google-workspace

My website is showing bugous google maps.
I need to upgrade the code to use the new google maps api access.
I have filled the google maps platform form (https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/?hl=pt-BR) but i have the following error:

Google Cloud Platform service has been disabled. Please contact your administrator to restore service.

I have and old google apps accounts (50 free users) and I have not upgraded to a google suite plan (nor intend to do so).

I have searched my g suite admin for a google cloud platform or a "google developer console"  service to enable, but none are available to be enabled.
(like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45603145/unable-to-create-project-in-google-cloud-cloud-service-disabled-by-admin-plea) and other links)

I have also tried to log into google cloud platform and create a billing account for my organisation (that worked), but when i try to create a new project, i have got the same error message (Google Cloud Platform service has been disabled. Please contact your administrator to restore service.)

Can anyone help me please!

Comment: May it's better asking this in a google developer forum?

Comment: Well i'd love to hear from someone from google and have a decent support, but honestly i did not find anyway to contact them (i did filled some forms online but still i have not had any answer). The reason i've asked here is because the google maps platform website tells me so, you can see in this link: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/, and also here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/support

Comment: Questions here should be about coding issues.

Comment: This is a pre-req for coding, and has just changed this past weekend. This is a reasonable question for someone to ask here (though perhaps w/o the technically unrelated google-maps tags), and I hope someone is able to answer. If I find out what's up, I'll update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out that there's a direct link: https://admin.google.com/{{your-url}}/AdminHome?hl=en#AppDetails:service=Google+Developers+Console

You can bet this won't be supported for long if they're trying to get people away from this, so hopefully we'll have a supported answer soon.

Comment: after receiving a response from google support I could find the google developers console on my g suite admin settings. Thank you for your response it does leads me directly to the service.

Comment: Thanks @jgggr, can you tell us where in the g suite admin settings you found it?  Or did they add it somehow for you?  I don't see it there, and searching for it still leads to the Apps page which no longer lists it.

Comment: This is the answer i've got from support:
"In order for your Google Cloud Platform to be enabled, please follow the below steps:
1.) Go to Admin Console > Apps > Additional Google Services
2.) Looked for Google Developer Console
3.) Turn it on"
**After** I received this message i could find the google developer console on the apps page

Comment: @jgggr does that make sense to you?  Step 2.) is where Google Developer Console doesn't exist anymore.