# How to enable "Cloud Service" in G Suite?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-workspace

If the "Cloud Service" is turned off on a G Suite domain, this disables the ability for all users in the G Suite domain from creating Projects in Google Cloud Platform.

If you are in this situation and you try to create a project in GCP from the Cloud Console, using the gcloud tool, or via the API directly, you will receive the following error:

`APPHOSTING_ADMIN Cloud Service disabled by admin. Please contact admin to restore service. com.google.apps.framework.request.StatusException: generic::FAILED_PRECONDITION: APPHOSTING_ADMIN Cloud Service disabled by admin. Please contact admin to restore service`

Formerly, the fix for this would have been to go into the G Suite Admin Console and enable the "Google Developers Console".

Related issue: [Unable to create project in Google Cloud: "Cloud Service disabled by admin. Please contact admin to restore service"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45603145/unable-to-create-project-in-google-cloud-cloud-service-disabled-by-admin-plea)

However, the "Google Developers Console" has been removed from the G Suite Admin Console list of Additional Google Services.

If you create a new G Suite domain and the Google Developers Console is not enabled by default, then you will never be able to create GCP Projects with accounts in that domain because there is no way to turn it back on.

How can a G Suite domain that does not have the Google Developers Console enabled get it switched on so that the domain users can create GCP Projects?

Comment: I *suspect* this may be related to the evolution of IAM in GCP. Maybe of help for understanding the relationship between GSuite and GCP would be the [Resource Hierarchy](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/cloud-platform-resource-hierarchy) article and in particular the [Link with G Suite or Cloud Identity accounts](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/cloud-platform-resource-hierarchy#link-with-g-suite-or-cloud-id-accounts) section. It *might* be a matter of mapping resources/identities and/or assigning the proper roles/permissions.

Comment: I believe the issue is that GCP is still doing a PRECONDITION check in G Suite to make sure the GCP service is turned on in G Suite. However, Google has removed the ability to toggle the GCP service on/off in G Suite Admin Console, so if your domain is in this strange situation, there is no way to toggle it back. I believe a fix would be to remove the precondition check or to make sure GCP is enabled on all existing G Suite domains and newly created domains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google has re-added the "Google Developers Console" to the G Suite Admin Console list of "Additional Google Services":

[image]

By enabling this service, you can then begin creating projects in GCP with accounts in your G Suite domain.

Google may be in the process of replacing this option with a new "Google Cloud Platform" option.

Answer (score 3):

According to my conversation with G Suite Support today, this is due to:

"The thing is that, we are replacing the Google Developer Console setting in the Google Admin Console with a new Google Cloud Platform application and it seems to be taking more time than expected."

The completion date was supposed to be today, but currently they had no ETA.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to have been fixed now - I can now see Developers console in [GSuite Admin -> Apps -> Addtional Google Services](https://admin.google.com/ac/appslist/additional).