# Google Cloud doesn't allow me to create my first project with admin role

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-iam

I'm trying to create my first project in google cloud with organization's administrator account. I have access to the administrator's email and passwords and I am logging in with that account to do so. The problem is that when I click on create new project I receive the following error:

```
There was an error while loading /home/dashboard?project=proven-now-305315&authuser=1.

You are missing at least one of the following required permissions:
Project

resourcemanager.projects.get
Check that the project ID is valid and you have permissions to access it. Learn more

Send feedback
```

The detail is that in my resource administration panel I already gave the permission that they ask me to the resource as shown in the following image:[image]

As I have read, the project IAM Admin role should grant the `resourcemanager.projects.get` role and as you can see in the image the resource rcv @ .. which is the administrator has it activated, however I keep trying to create a new project and it doesn't allow me to do it. Any idea?

Comment: I had a look at this and think your approach is correct. I initially wondered whether you'd created the project **outside** of your org and did not have permission to list those but, that's not correct as you have `Project IAM Admin`. I asked a friend (who has an Org) and he is able to repro your issue. Curiously, when he tried to do this, his URL included `authuser=3` (**not** `authuser=1` as you have).

Comment: It would appear that `authuser=#` reflects which multi-user account you're using. IIUC, you're likely logged into Chrome with mulitple accounts and, for some reason, the URLs reflecting the wrong user. Perhaps try running a different browser or going icognito, only logging in as `rcv@` and then trying this?

Comment: Please login as rvc@ user in cloud console then issue the following gloud command to create project under the org "gcloud projects create PROJECT_ID --organization=ORGANIZATION_ID" and let us know the stuats

Comment: @Mahboob this is what I got `ERROR: (gcloud.projects.create) FAILED_PRECONDITION: Google Cloud Platform service has been disabled. Please contact your administrator to restore service.
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.PreconditionFailure
  violations:
  - description: Google Cloud Platform service has been disabled. Please contact your
      administrator to restore service.
    type: SERVICE`

Comment: @DazWilkin I got the same answer, I have tried incognito, login only with rcv and using Edge. Maybe has something to do with the try free period that I have'nt accepted yet?

Comment: Note that in addition to the given answers, if your Google Workspace account is on the initial 14-day free trial, you won't be able to create GCP projects, with a similar error.  Enable the paid plan under Billing/Subscriptions in the Admin Console, and then you can.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was for some reason the Google Cloud was disable for all users, I solved following this instructions.  [Solved with this!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56329284/13291091)

> To activate this service, please follow the steps:
>
> 1. Access the admin console and go to Apps -> Additional Google Services
> 2. Look for the service “Google Cloud Platform” and click on the box next to it
> 3. In to top right corner click in “ON”
> 4. Confirm you want to turn it on in the pop-up box.

Answer (score 8):

In case anybody else, like me, reaches this answer, I want to point out that the accepted answer is correct, but for me I had to also make sure that within the settings, I ensured that **Project Creation Settings** on the right pane and under the section of **Cloud Resource Manager Api Settings** was set to on. It was turned off by default. Many people on my team overlooked this as it is significantly smaller text.

This may be an option that was not present before or it was turned on by default in the past. For us, it was turned off.

Please refer to the included image for a visual representation of the
[settings that need to be turned on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kzFC.png).

Comment: Good information. Your question should have included the detail that you are using Google Workspace. That is an important detail and affects which permissions need to be set up and verified.

Comment: I spent 2 days trying to figure this out before finding the screenshot in the above post that solved it for me.  None of the other solutions on the internet mentioned this easy to miss setting.

Comment: Thank you! From both me and my busy client who I was able to guide through the process of giving me the permissions I need quickly thanks to your screenshot.

Comment: The screenshot image was super helpful. Thank you